# Do Indians still believe the sacred cows?

Tags: belief, cows

Sorry for the blunt title. I'm trying to understand the modern Indian segment of the population, those who have computers and are connected to the Internet.

How much are religious? How much traditional? Is there a significant phenomenon of secularization? Are, for example, there high-tech and technology persons that will stop for a cow?

Sorry for the ignorance and perhaps exclusions. I do not specialize in this area and the question just popped in my mind.

Comment: Welcome to the site sir, could you please clarify the q a bit? Do you want a statistic (impossible) or an opinion, which is not fit on this site?

Comment: What makes you think being modern makes us less religious? They are totally different aspects of our lives. Sure we don't stop our vehicles on the road every time we see a cow to pray, but that does not show disrespect. There are many roads in many cities here, where cows take their time to cross it or simply sleep on it. Most people do not bother the cows; we change lanes and continue driving. Believing that cows are sacred, is a part of our culture and will continue to remain so, however high tech we become.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are cows given special importance?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/321/why-are-cows-given-special-importance)