# What is the main reason behind praying to animals like mice, monkeys and cows?

Tags: worship, animals, cows

I'm a little confused as to why Hindus worship animals like mice, monkeys and cows. I have searched on the internet but I didn't find any answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are cows given special importance?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/321/why-are-cows-given-special-importance)

Comment: Not only cows. Mice monkeys etc all of them got special importance. Why? Is there any special logic behind this?

Comment: Where do people worship mice? Only temple I know of is in Rajasthan, India ([Karni Mata Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karni_Mata_Temple)). But I don't think they worship mice there. They just get 'special treatment'.

Comment: Coz Ganesha is depicted using mouse as a vehicle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is denigrating question and shows no research

Comment: All the gods have different vehicles do you mean Hindus care about all of them? Some temples give special treatment to some animals like mouse in case of Karni Mata temple but that's because its part of the "miracle" there, there is a temple in Kerala where people giv food to alligator, that does not mean all Hindus worship alligator, praying and caring are two different things, Hindus respect nature because of their importance, except of cow no other animal is "prayed" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For cows** you can read here [Why are cows given special importance?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/321/why-are-cows-given-special-importance)

Also do read the [following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamadhenu):

> Kamadhenu (Sanskrit: कामधेनु, [kaːməˈd̪ʱeːnʊ], Kāmadhenu), also known
>   as Surabhi (सुरभि, Surabhī), is a divine bovine-goddess described in
>   Hinduism as the mother of all cows. She is a miraculous "cow of
>   plenty" who provides her owner whatever he desires and is often
>   portrayed as the mother of other cattle

**For monkeys:**

Simply coz Hanuman represents the monkey clan, Lord Hanuman is born in Vanara Clan ( Son of Vayu and Anjana).

**For mouse:**

The mouse is depicted as the vahan (vehicle) of Lord Ganesha hence mouse. It has an interesting story too as stated [here](http://www.biodiversityofindia.org/index.php?title=Why_Lord_Ganesha_has_a_mouse_as_his_vehicle):

The mythological story, according to Ganesha Purana goes like this:

> There was a celestial musician-god by the name Krauncha. One day, in
>   the court of Lord Indra, Krauncha accidentally stepped on the foot of
>   Muni Vamadeva, who (as all Munis), got enraged and cursed Krauncha to
>   become a mouse. However, Krauncha became a huge mountain-sized mouse
>   and ended up damaging everything in its path. Once, he ended up
>   stepping on the ashram of Maharshi Parashar, with whom Lord Ganesha
>   was staying, and destroying it. Lord Ganesha, inorder to teach
>   Krauncha a lesson, unleashed his pasha (noose) on Krauncha which ended
>   up looping around the mouse and bringing him to Lord Ganesha's feet.
>   Ganesha then said something like, "Krauncha...you have caused a lot of
>   trouble and you deserve a severe punishment. But since you ask for my
>   forgiveness, I will pardon you and use you as my vehicle". However,
>   when Ganesha mounted on Krauncha, he couldnt bear the weight of Lord
>   Ganesha. Krauncha pleaded for Ganesha to become light-weight so that
>   he could support him. Lord Ganesha obliged and since then, has been
>   using the mouse as his vehicle.

**For peacocks:**

The peacock is depicted as the vahan (vehicle) of Lord Kartikeya hence peacock.

> Kartikeya carries on one hand a spear and his other hand is always
>   blessing devotees. His vehicle is a peacock, a pious bird that grips
>   with its feet a serpent, which symbolizes the ego and desires of
>   people. The peacock represents the destroyer of harmful habits and the
>   conqueror of sensual desires. The symbolism of Kartikeya thus points
>   to the ways and means of reaching perfection in life.

Comment: Would it be safe, then, to say no one *worships* these animals? I have understood it more like how Christians made reliquaries of thorns from the crown of thorns and splinters from the cross. They aren't given devotion, but do induce a sense of awe due to their connection to the divine. Is this accurate?

Comment: @RubelliteFae true, the animals are not "prayed" too, there are many animals which are vahanas of gods, you don't see Hindus worshipping lions, it's more of respect nature kind of thing.

Comment: I watched that on discovery that in India there is a mandir where a large number of mice are present and hindu people go there to see them and for hindus mandir is a place of praying that’s why i was asking that