# When will god protect?

Tags: krishna, gods, dharma

I have heard god protects the good. I have heard Krishna saying jab jab dharm ki hani hoti hain tab tab main ata hu. But then why is not adharm getting over. Why god doesnt stop crimes.It is making me doubt the whole idea.Why god is not finishing adharm if god can do it? When will god finish all the crime.

Answer (score 2):

God does not normally interfere with the working of the world.

**God only helps Yogis**.

> Whoever, being devoted to me solely, engage themselves always in
> contemplation and worship of Me - to such ever-steadfast devotees I
> ensure the procurement of all their wants (enlightenment) and the
> preservation of their assets (worldly interests).

**Gita 9.22**

Comment: But I have heard the killing of pandits or sanyasis , why didnt god interfere then?

Comment: And how do we make this understand to children?

Comment: Do you think everybody who claims to be a yogi is really one? Recently a top Sannyasi in South India committed suicide. Tell children what I have already written that God does not normally interfere in running the universe. An analogy is the Sun which provides the energy to make earth livable bot does not tell us what we should do.

Comment: But cow is divine and we hear the slaughtering of cow then and now, why isnt god interfering then?And will god not protect atheist?And are you sure there is not enough injustice so that god shouldnt interfere?People making money in name of dharma?And do you have any definite proof that god really helps yogi?

Comment: Read my answer to this post to understand the position of a cow. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/49108/do-hindus-worship-cows-in-some-way

Comment: God simply doesn't normally interfere in the universe. Didi God stop the deaths of people in the recent Covid pandemic? He didn't.

Comment: So will god not protect an atheist ?

Comment: God will normally not protect either a devotee or an atheist. Most people will have to live their lives based on their karma. God will only protect someone who has made some progress in purifying his mind. You have to purify your mind to connect with God. If you don't have that connection your life will be determined by your karma.

Comment: Then why don't someone ask for a boon to eliminate crime and injustice from the world?

Comment: Good question. This is what Sri Ramakrishna said, "You may then ask, 'How, then can one explain misery, and sin and unhappiness?' The answer is that these apply to the jiva. Brahman is unaffected by them. There is poison in a snake; but though others may die if bitten by it, the snake itself is not affected by the poison. " Only one who has developed connection with Brahman is free from injustice. Crime and injustice are parts of the package deal of the universe. There is no boon to eliminate crime and injustice because then the universe has to be eliminated.

Comment: Why god works in such a subtle way and why just doesnt show herself/himself?How I can believe what you are saying is true?

Comment: Why is god waiting for kali yug to end, isnt it quite depressing if the world end like this?Isnt there a more optimistic way for the world to end?

Comment: And if God stopped the disrobing of Draupadi then why doesn't he/she protect every other women?

Comment: Sorry, there is no optimistic end of the universe. Even Earth's surface temperature will rise to 1000 degrees in 2 billion years and life would disappear long before that. That is the truth. Draupadi knew Lord Krishna personally and thus had a direct connection. How many women or for that matter men have such direct connections with God?

Comment: Then why didn't God protected Sita ma from ravana clutches the first time? Why didnt God protected jatayu even he had a direct connection with god, the same applies to abhimanyu?

Comment: God did ultimately protect Sita. How God would do the protection is up to Him. Jatayu most probably didn't ask God for protection. Abhimanyu was supremely confident of his arms and didn't ask for protection.

Comment: Then why didnt god protected Rambha?@Pradip Gangopadhyay

Comment: Has god ever helped you?@PradipGangopadhyay