# Why doesn't god interfere in the working of the world?

Tags: scripture, vedas

Related: [When will god protect?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/52991/23020)

If we all are the children of God why doesn't protect us all? Why doesn't god interfere if something bad is happening to good people?
How could one have so much faith?

Any doesn't god protect good people?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do bad things happen to good people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9563/why-do-bad-things-happen-to-good-people)

Comment: no sir@Rāmachandra

Comment: Ok, Chk out [this](https://os.me/why-do-bad-things-happen-to-good-people/) beautiful ans by my Gurudeva!