# What is the reason of god not interfering in the working of the world?

Tags: krishna, brahma, creation

In the answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/53004 god only helps yogis but the question is why? What is the reason of god not interfering? Why doesn't god interfere in the working of the world?

Answer (score 1):

As a practicing Vaishnava in Vaishnav Sampradaya. In my opinion, the lord Narayana constantly interferes in the working world. Think of it like as, you are in Treta-yuga or Dwapar-yuga, and lord Narayana takes the avatar in the form of Lord Ram and Lord Krrishna, will you be able to identify them as Narayan.

There are various texts, some say there are only 10 avatars, some 24 and some 30. But these texts are only able to identify some avatars and write them. Because there are infinite avatars of lord Narayana. Same case with lord Shiva and avatars.

God helps his bhakta's who are in need of help. We may not see an avatar like Ram or Krishna. But the Lord appears in the Kali-Yuga also. Some are very powerful, visually pleasing and relevant avatars, some are not. Lord Narayana is constantly helping his bhaktas, we are not able to see it because we don't believe it.

Just because we see adharma rise, doesn't mean lord didn't appear in the world. The Lord appears to help bhaktas, not to set the order in the right direction as the Kalki avatar will do in the end of this 28th MahaYug.
Reference - Shrimad Bhagwat Geeta

Comment: Sir/Madam are sure about your opinions there are so many different answers for the same question.I am confused whom to believe because unlike a science experiment I cant proof it.Can you?